# Splitting file by line start using Unix

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, unix, awk

I need to split a file using Unix by the first tag of the file.

The **original file** looks like:

```
TAG ANIMAL
A CAT
B CAT  
C CAT
D DOG
A DOG
```

The result files should look like this (post split):

**File 1**

```
TAG ANIMAL  
A CAT  
A DOG
```

**File 2**

```
TAG ANIMAL  
B CAT
```

**File 3**

```
TAG ANIMAL  
C CAT
```

**File 4**

```
TAG ANIMAL  
D DOG
```

Attempts:
I tried  split -p A filename prefix, but this only works for sorted data and thus A CAT & A DOG end up in different files. I also get a 3 other random files from this, which are unneeded.

Answer (score 1):

This awk one-liner will help you:

```
awk 'NR==1{t=$0;next}!a[$1]{print t>$1}{print >>$1;a[$1]=1;close($1)}' file
```

If we test with your example, after you execute the awk cmd, you will get `A,B,C,D` four files.

```
kent$  cat f
TAG ANIMAL
A CAT
B CAT  
C CAT
D DOG
A DOG

kent$  awk 'NR==1{t=$0;next}!a[$1]{print t>$1}{print >>$1;a[$1]=1;close($1)}' f

kent$  head {A..D}
==> A <==
TAG ANIMAL
A CAT
A DOG

==> B <==
TAG ANIMAL
B CAT  

==> C <==
TAG ANIMAL
C CAT

==> D <==
TAG ANIMAL
D DOG
```

Comment: The usage of `close` could be overkill if there are not a lot of tags.

Comment: @kvantour we don't know how does OP's input look like. Even Op himself might not make sure how the input could be. With `close`, the script will always work, but without it the script could fail. So I put it in there.

Comment: It was just a generic comment. I fully agree with you.

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
 split [options] filename prefix

  it will split your file in unix
```

Comment: When I run this, I get an error that split [options] is no such file or directory.

Comment: this doesn't do what OP wants

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in Python by creating a `split_file.py` scrip as follows:

```
original_file = open('original_file.txt', 'r')
file_contents = []
for line in original_file:
    file_contents.append(line.split())

tags = {c[0] for c in file_contents[1:]}
for tag in tags:
    file_name = 'file_{}.txt'.format(tag)
    new_file = open(file_name, 'w')
    new_file.write('{} {}\n'.format(file_contents[0][0], file_contents[0][1]))
    for content in file_contents:
        if content[0] == tag:
            new_file.write('{} {}\n'.format(content[0], content[1]))

    new_file.close()
```

This script assumes that your original file is called `original_file.txt` and it will create new files called `file_<tag name>.txt`.

You can call

> python split_file.py

to execute it.